# Docker-compose postgres volume not persisting

Tags: docker, docker-compose, volumes

Not sure why, my docker compose file is:

```
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ods:/var/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=ods

volumes:
  ods:
```

when I do `docker volume ls` I can see the line

`local  postgres_ods`

has been created (not sure why it has added postgres_ to the front)

I will then create a table, save it, commit it, add some data to it.

do a  `docker compose down` then a `docker compose up -d`

I find that the data and the table has gone missing.

inspecting `postgres_ods` gives me:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2021-11-17T00:26:15Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.project": "postgres",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "2.0.0",
            "com.docker.compose.volume": "ods"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/postgres_ods/_data",
        "Name": "postgres_ods",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong folder mapped, that is why the data didn't stick around:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ods:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=ods

volumes:
  ods:
```

Comment: As James said - the volume path must be correct. 
If you are using a different postgres image like the bitnami one - make sure you use the right path (`/bitnami/postgresql`).